# Eclipse/JUnit "Test class not found" when subclassing BlockJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, ide, junitparams

I am trying to subclass `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`, in order to be able to use 
this nice parameterizing framework: [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams).

I can't use the built-in JUnit parameterizing runner, since I need to do some additional work in the runner.
Anyway, eclipse will run the tests, but when trying to double-click the JUnit display in order to jump to the test code, it prompts a "Test class not found in selected project" error.

Does anyone happen to know where in the Runner code can I set the connection between the JUnit plugin and the code?

Comment: Is there an error log in Eclipse (look in the Error Log view). If so, can you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: I don't see any error in the Error Log View.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of 'this nice parameterizing framework' ;-)

The problem (which is also in `JUnitParams`) is that eclipse uses the junit's Description class when jumping to a test method, but in order to show the tree with all parameters in the junit results view I need to cheat a bit and enter parameters as a method name and method name as a class name, hence the problem.

If you need this feature, change `getDescription` method in your runner so that it works like the original one (but you'll loose the nice view of which param set failed.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, and for your framework as well :-)